# How does Google Earth calculate the inverse geodesic problem, in particular the forward azimuth?

Tags: google-earth, geodesy, geodetic

Comparing the result of Vincenti’s formulae as implemented in https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve with the output of Google Earth Pro I find a striking difference in results for azimuth. GeodSolve will calculate the distance between the base of the flagpole on top of the White House at N 38° 53.862 W 077° 02.193 and the base of the flagpole on top of Buckingham Palace at N 51° 30.081 W 000° 08.513 as 5,912,893.79 meters with a forward azimuth of 49.387°, whereas Google Earth Pro (using the ruler) will give 5,912,887.89 meters with a forward azimuth of 49.36°. While the difference in distance is negligible, the difference in azimuth is not.

Taking the first point (WH) as start and making a projection in Google Earth using the results of GeodSolve will yield a point in Battersea Park at approximately N 51° 28.748 W 000° 09.222 more than 2,600 meters away from Buckingham Palace. I checked on the impact of height settings but taking an absolute height of 3m as opposed to “at ground” does not make a noticeable difference on the azimuth and only very few meters on the distance. Could it be that the azimuth is calculated as in great circle spheric geometry?

Answer (score 1):

After two days I found the answer to that question myself. . I am not sure if I should just delete my post or leave it there together with this answer. Well, maybe someone else wants to know too.
Google Earth does not have a projection tool per se, what it does is that it calculates distance and azimuth as you drag the path- or distance measurement tool along. First it calculates the distance as applicable for WGS84 geoid. Then, it takes the central angle of distance (σ₁₂), thus avoiding the question of the radius of an auxiliary sphere, and calculates the forward azimuth with Haversine or equivalent formulae for great circle computations